# How to remove items from list in other class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem here, I need to do method pop but I can only use functions from SimpleList, any ideas?

I can only modify class RingBuffer so I can't use remove(), pop() etc.

```
from typing import Optional, List

# (‹sl› is instance of ‹SimpleList›):
#
#  • ‹sl.append(x)› adds to the end of list ‹x›,
#  • ‹sl.get(i)› returns value of index ‹i›,
#  • ‹sl.size()› returns current size of list,
#  • ‹sl.set(i, x)› sets index ‹i› to value ‹x›.

class RingBuffer:

    def __init__(self, size: int, storage: 'SimpleList'):
        self.sl = storage
        self.size = size

    def push(self, value: int) -> bool:
        if self.sl.size() >= self.size:
            return False
        else:
            self.sl.append(value)
            return True

    # Method ‹pop› removes first value from list and returns it.
    # If list is empty, method doesn't do anything and returns ‹None›.

    def pop(self) -> Optional[int]:
        if self.sl.size() == 0:
            return None

class SimpleList:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__items: List[int] = []
    def append(self, x: int) -> None:
        self.__items.append(x)
    def get(self, i: int) -> int:
        return self.__items[i]
    def set(self, i: int, x: int) -> None:
        self.__items[i] = x
    def size(self) -> int:
        return len(self.__items)
```

Comment: I don't see any way to do it with only those methods.

Comment: `RingBuffer` should keep track of the current index in the `SimpleList`. Popping gets that element and then increments the index.

Comment: Why would you create the simplelist class when python list already have thoses features?

Comment: @Fredericka To learn to work with classes :/

Comment: @Barmar How I can I do it?

Comment: That's for you to figure out. That's the point of the assignment.

Comment: I got it to work on my side, i will give you an hint. There is 4 steps: 1. Get the full list from the SimpleList. 2. Reset the Simple list. 3. Reassign all the element from step1 except the one you need. 4. Return the desired value

Comment: @Fredericka How do you reset?

Comment: There are no methods in `SimpleList` that remove elements, so you can't pop anything off of one. It would be possible to do it directly from outside the class.

Comment: It is totaly possible to resset, get a look at your class SimpleList, wich method sets the list to en empty list? @Leerifle

Comment: @Fredericka oh you mean init

Comment: Yeah, i don't know if you are allowed to reuse the __init__, but it is working this way.

Comment: @Fredericka I think I can reuse so it should be fine,  hank you very much. :)

Comment: @Fredericka: Although the `__init__()` method is usually use implicitly for initializing newly created instances, it *is* possible to explicitly call it on an existing one — although doing so would be fairly unorthodox. I suggest you post an answer.

Comment: @martineau, yeah i know but do you see an other way without modifying the SimpleList class?

Comment: I have problem here with mypy: "Cannot access "__init__" directly", can I somehow fix that?

Comment: @Fredericka: As I said, it would be possible by directly accessing the internals of the class instance.

Comment: Leerifle: You can do it regardless of what mypy says.

Comment: I have a better solution, instead of using __init__, just create a new instance of the class. self.sl = SimpleList()

Comment: Alright, that worked, thanks @Fredericka

Comment: @Fredericka: It's unclear whether creating a new instance of `SimpleList` would count as having popped something off (i.e. removing it from) the original if that is what you mean.

Comment: @martineau, i get it, my solution is unorthodox, but i am just trying to figure out something that meets que requirements. Also, you don't think creating a new instance, copying the old list except the first element counts as a pop?

Comment: @Fredericka: I said explicitly calling `__init__()` would be unorthodox. Since the `pop()` method is being implemented in the `RingBuffer` class, it doesn't really matter how it accomplishes what it does I suppose, as long as it works (and mypy doesn't complain about it). This is probably only some kind of homework or learning exercise anyway, not a real-world code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you figured it out, but just for you to compare:

```
def pop(self) -> Optional[int]:
    if self.sl.size() == 0:
        return None
    
    l = [(self.sl.get(x)) for x in range(self.sl.size())]
    self.sl = SimpleList()
    [self.sl.append(x) for x in l[1:]]
    return l[0]
```

Comment: Yea, that works fine, mine is just too complicated :D

Comment: @martineau Got it

Comment: Fredericka: FWIW creating a list just for its side-effects is not only unorthodox it's also inefficient and generally considered a poor programming practice.